# adding element reference as object property in js

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I'm trying to assign a reference to a DOM element to a property when declaring an object but it won't work like this:

```
var myMedia = {
 "v" : document.getElementById("video"),
 "a" : document.getElementById("audio"),
 "g" : "myMediaGroup",
};
```

...myMedia.v returns null, but if I assign it like this:

```
myMedia.v = document.getElementById("video");
```

...it works great.

Using object-literal, can I only assign strings to properties? How could I do it differently?

Comment: Are you sure your DOM is loaded when defining the object literal?

Comment: Don't put a comma after the last element of your object initializer:`"g" : "myMediaGroup"`

Comment: @rplantiko There is no problem with having a trailing commas in an Object litteral or an Array. Actually, it helps prevent errors when adding new properties/elements later. http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5

Comment: @rplantiko the trailing comma will be ignored by the parsing engine.

Comment: @Xufox, you were right. I'm too tired right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. The script tag was in the head of the document and not below the audio and video tags. It just couldn't find the elements :P